# Prove that in each coloring of a $4\times7$ board in two colors there's a square that all four of it's corners are colored by the same color

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> Prove that in each coloring of a $4\times7$ board in two colors there's a square that all four of it's corners are colored by the same color.

This is a pigeon hole principle question and I have a [proposed solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VncY7.jpg) that I totally don't understand.

An explanation or a different approach would be appreciated.

Comment: If any column of four has three or more squares of the same color, then it is relatively easy to show that you cannot achieve this. That leaves the case of having two squares of both colors on each column. But ${4\choose 2}=6$, so after six columns you have to repeat a column, and that's your contradiction.

Comment: Do you mean "square" or "rectangle"? Some extra work will be required to find a square (if indeed it is possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true if "square" is taken literally, e.g., $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ is a counter-example (found by hand; verified computationally).

If "square" is interpreted to mean $2 \times 2$ submatrix, then we can prove the claim for $3 \times 7$ boards as follows.

In the first row, there must be $4$ cells of the same color, say blue.  In the second row, directly below these $4$ cells we must have $3$ cells of the other color, say red, otherwise we have a monochromatic $2 \times 2$ submatrix.  In the third row, directly below these $3$ cells we must have either $2$ red or $2$ blue cells, and in either case, we have a monochromatic $2 \times 2$ submatrix.

Comment: I thought maybe a square could be avoided in such a small matrix. Nice construction.

Comment: +1 Oops. I `recognized' an old contest-math training problem, and didn't read it carefully enough (thinking rectangles all the way). Well done.